# Converting e.timeStamp into the current date/time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, events, unix-timestamp

I've set an event listner on an 'li' element which contains a span element that should output the current date.

I have the following lines of code:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(e.timeStamp);
var showDate = date.toDateString();
$(this).append('<span class="date-clicked">' + showDate + '</span>');
```

the idea is to use the event objects 'timeStamp' property to obtain the number of milliseconds from Jan 1st 1970 (epoch/unix time) and then using var showDate to get the right date format to display in the span element inside the respective li element.

I'm using firefox btw.

Each time I click an li element its showing me the epoch time 'Thu Jan 01 1970' instead of what i want to see which is 'Thu Feb 13 2020'.

is there a way I can get e.timeStamp to show me the CURRENT Date instead of the epoch/unix date ?

any pointers or tips in the right direction appreciated folks. Thanks.

Comment: What is `e.timeStamp`? Since `e.timeStamp` doesn't return anything (likely to be `undefined`), of course setTime will simply set the date to the first timestamp of the unix time.

Comment: Guess you can create date like this: `var date = new Date(e.timeStamp)`...

Comment: the first line of code creates a new Date object and its time is set to the time at which the event was clicked ( second line).  The time the event was clicked is then converted into a date that can be read (third line).

Comment: Interestingly, I tried your suggestion Terry but it doesn't achieve what I'm gunning for. Observe:

    var date = new Date(e.timeStamp);
  console.log(date);
  var clicked = date.toDateString();

The above still outputs the epoch time when viewed in the console heh

Comment: Why don't you just use 'new Date()' instead of 'showDate' like $(this).append('<span class="date-clicked">' + new Date() + '</span>');

Comment: If `e.timeStamp` is a Unix timestamp, it's in seconds, and you need to multiply by 1000 before setting the time. If `e.timeStamp` is a JS timestamp, then it should be working.

Answer (score 2):

@Manny D, I think we may be working from the same book as the code you posted looks almost identical to the problem I had. This is the code I used to solve the problem, eo is for event object, by the way. I added a forward slash to make it look neater as well...

```
    $(function() {  
            $("li").on("click", function(eo) {
            
                $("li span").remove();
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(eo.timeStamp);                 
                $(this).append("<span class='date'> / " + new Date().toDateString() + "</span>");
```

Comment: This will always show today's date... (`new Date()` returns the current date). I think you want `date.toDateString()`...